Sum of N uniform random variables - no information about dependence
I've been given the following question:
You are given n random variables, $X_1$, $X_2$ ..., and $X_N$. Each of these variables has a uniform distribution that ranges from 0 to 1. Your task is to determine the probability that the sum of these variables, denoted as S, is less than equal to 1. Can you solve this problem?
I noticed that this question doesn't specify whether these uniform random variables are independent or not i.e. even though they have an identical distribution, we don't know whether they are IID.
Can we still say that the solution is $\frac{1}{n!}$?

If the variables are so dependent to the extent that they are all the same, then the probability that $S \leq 1 $ is just $1/n$. Or, if $X_2 = 1 - X_1$, then clearly $S \geq 1$ so the probability is 0. So, the answer would be "No, need more information".

We need the joint PDF. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402520/pdf-of-sum-of-two-dependent-random-variables

The independence of the random variables is key to answering this problem. For example, we could have two random variables $X_1,X_2$ where $X_2=1-X_1$. These can still be uniform, but the probability that $X_1+X_2\leq1$ equals 1, since $X_1+X_2=1$. You could create a similar set up where 4 variables sum to 2, which makes the probability 0. We can't make any statements on $P(X_1+X_2\leq1)$ without assuming the variables are independent or having other information.
